# modify SQL query to allow form criteria

Tags: c#, sql

This query works

```
SELECT 
    branch
    , total
    , typeA/1.2 AS [A]
    , typeB/1.2 AS [B]
    , dates
    , (typeA / 1.2 + typeB / 1.2) * 0.2 AS [V]
    , (typeA / 1.2 + typeB / 1.2) * 0.2 + typeA / 1.2 + typeB / 1.2 - total AS [DIFF]
FROM 
    detail
WHERE
    (branch = 'SW1'
     AND method in ('Visa', 'Mcard') OR branch = 'SW1'
     AND method = 'Coupon'
     AND receipt = 'Y' OR branch = 'SW1' 
     AND method = 'Coupon'
     AND qty <= 7)
    AND dates Between '04/01/2015' And '04/30/2015'
ORDER BY 
    dates;
```

But I need to get the branch data from a control on a form as in

```
Select("branch = " + ComboBox1.Text).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have 3 conditions in the query that refer to branch.
How do I remove the multiple references to the same branch so I can use the form control in c#. I have
tried shifting branch to all sorts of positions after the
WHERE clause

Comment: Learn to use parentheses. For one, this is completely unreadable, and for two, once you do, you'll see how easy it is to make sure you only need `branch='SW1'` once. That said, *don't* do this - you're opening your application to SQL injection. Only get the value you want to compare it from the UI, and then build your query appropriately, passing the values as parameters to the parametrized query.

Comment: what's the question? you need help with the sql code or the c# code?

Comment: please clear your question about c# or in sql side or linq side(your last code line suggest linq)

Comment: The criteria for branch has to be retrieved from a control on a form but this query contains 3 references to branch. How can I reduce the references to  1 instead of 3. I am not an expert in SQL but learning as I go along

Comment: @Ajay2707 The SQL query will be behind a button on a c# form. The form will have a control which will provide the data for branch

Answer (score 0):

Have worked it out, by trial and error.
As follows from the Where clause onwards

```
WHERE  dates Between '04/01/2015' And '04/30/2015' 
       AND (method in ('Visa','MCard') 
       OR method= 'Coupon'AND receipt='Y'
       OR method='Coupon' AND qty<=5)
       AND branch='SW1'
```